# How to search foreignkeys with accent

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Description(models.Model):
    language = CharField() # choices are Italian, English
    product = ForeignKey(Product)
    description = TextField()
```

How do I filter both `name` field and `description` text field and also take into consideration of accents.

For example, Caffe and Caffè

Comment: What exactly do you want to filter or find in your database? Find a description that it's product has some specific name?

Comment: I would like to find a `string` either in `name` or `description`

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @IainShelvington Postgres

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/lookups/#unaccent

Comment: @IainShelvington Thank you, this is exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use OR conditions in sending queries to your database:

```py
from django.db.models import Q
q_txt = 'Caffe'
q = Description.objects.filter(Q(description=q_txt) | Q(product.name=q_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can first filter in PRODUCT by disire ID then you can filter the DESCRIPTION like this

```
from django.db.models import Q
p = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=?).first()
d = Description.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=?) | Q(descriptio__icontains=?)) | Q(product=p)
```